# Multiple UIViewController working at the same time?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Is the possible for multiple UIViewControllers working at the same time? Consider the following window:

```
         +-----------------+         
         |  +-----+        |
         |  |     |        |
         |  |  A  |    C   |
         |  |     |        |
         |  +-----+        |
         |                 |
         |       +-----+   |
         |       |  B  |   |
         |       +-----+   |
         |                 |
         +-----------------+
```

`C` is the first UIViewController added to the window.

In viewDidLoad of C_ViewController, I added a NIB (A) by:

```
A_ViewController *avc = [[A_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"A_ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:avc.view];
[avc release];
```

A_ViewController is loaded and shown properly. However, if linking any event from the A_ViewController.xib to IBOutlet in A_ViewController.m (e.g. buttonClick), there is an error when the event is fired:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSCFString buttonClicked:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x5937a40'

The question, is it possible to have multiple UIViewController working at the same time? In this example, one for `C`, one for `A` and one for `B`.

ADDED: the header file of C_ViewController

```
    @class A_ViewController;

    @interface C_ViewController : UIViewController {
        A_ViewController *avc;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet A_ViewController *avc;

    @end
```

SOLUTION:

```
  A_ViewController *a = [[A_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"A_ViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:a.view];
  self.avc = a; // added this to fix!! Thanks
  [a release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried retaining your A_ViewController instance ?
I'm not sure the viewcontroller is retained by it's view.

Comment: I added the header file in the question.